# cakephp 2.x multi level relationship

Tags: cakephp, model

I am using cakephp 2.3.4

**how to define relationship in model for below table :**

**industries have multiple sub_industries.
client have mulitple industries and sub_industries.**

when i select any industry , selectbox is filtered with related sub_industries.

so i have created these tables.

**1.clients(id,full_name)
2.client_industries (id,client_id,industry_id)
3.client_sub_industries(id,client_industry_id,sub_industry_id)
4.industries(id,name)**
5.sub_industries(id,industry_id,name)

how to define relationship in model, how to bind model for it.

i am new in cakephp. please need a help..

Thanks

Comment: The formatting of your question makes it unclear what you mean - please edit the question to clarify what tables you have and what fields they contain.

Answer (score 0):

in Model of client you have something like

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Industry');
```

see [Linking Models cook book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#associations-linking-models-together)

Answer (score 0):

I think u want this use this in ur controller

```
$this->sub_industry->recursive=2;
$clintshavingindustrieshavingsubindustries= $this->sub_industry->find('all');
```

In your Clint Model

```
$hasMany='industr ';
```

In your Industry Model

```
$hasMany='sub_industry ';
```